# different redirects during different promise fails causes Error: cannot call http.ServerResponse.end()

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, promise

I have a chain of promises that could fail at different points.  Depending on where it fails, I might want it to do different things.  In some places I might want to render a page, other places redirect.  The problem I'm finding is when it runs through all the fail functions and then has errors with http.ServerResponse.end() being called numerous times.

Example:

```
Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() {
    if (apples) {
        return apples.fetch().fail(function() { res.redirect('/somewhere') } );
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}).then(function() {
    // doing other stuff
},function() {
    res.redirect('/elsewhere');
}).fail(function() {
    res.render('error.ejs');
});
```

Should I be doing this a different way?

( I start with as(1) just to get into the promise chain since there are two different starting cases of apples and !apples that both need to continue to the next part of the chain, but only one of them could start the chain since {} can't. Not sure if that's the best way to do that either. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like exceptions, you can throw different errors and get to different places.

```
Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() {
    if (apples) {
        return apples.fetch();
    } else {
        throw new Error("No Apples");
    }
}).then(function() {
    // doing other stuff
}).then(null,function(e) {
    if(e.message !== "No Apples"){ // can also subclass Error
        res.render("error.ejs");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/elsewhere");
    }
});
```

Note, like I said in your different question - what you really want is `.then(null,function(){` rather than `.fail` usually. It's a poor name choice for `.fail` on their side imo.

Because I like them, here is the synchronous analogy:

```
try {
    if(apples){
        var a = apples.fetch(); // might throw too
    } else{
        throw new Error("No Apples");
    }

}catch(e){
    if(e.message !== "No Apples"){ // can also subclass Error
        res.render("error.ejs");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/elsewhere");
    }
}
```